# search() string for multiple occurrences

Tags: javascript, string, search

Say you have the string, `Black cat jack black cat jack black cat jack`.

How would you use `search()` to find the 2nd occurence of the word `jack`?

I'm guessing the code would look something like:

```
var str = "Black cat jack black cat jack black cat jack";
var jack = str.search('jack');
```

But that will only return the location of the first occurrence of `jack` in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [indexof method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) in a loop

```
var pos = foo.indexOf("jack");
while(pos > -1) {
     pos = foo.indexOf("jack", pos+1);
}
```

Comment: `'someone has a nice jacket'.indexOf('jack'); //19`

Comment: i don't think regex is needed for such simple task. also you don't know what boundaries he needs. not to mention your solution won't work with words like jack-in-a-box. he can check the next symbol after the found word if boundaries are needed.

Comment: Well it can easily be adressed with a regex, while it's impossible using `indexOf` without explicitely knowing the boundaries, or calling `indexOf` multiple times which would be very inefficient. The `indexOf` solution is simple, but too naive from my point of view.

Answer (score 2):

### Usage recommendation

Note that [`String.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) method works with `RegExp` - if you supply a string then it will implicitly convert it into a `RegExp`. It more or less has the same purpose as `RegExp.test`, where you only want to know whether there is a match to the `RegExp` in the string.

If you want to search for fixed string, then I recommend that you stick with `String.indexOf`. If you really want to work with pattern, then you should use `RegExp.exec` instead to get the indices of all the matches.

### String.indexOf

If you are searching for a fixed string, then you can supply the position to resume searching to [`String.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
str.indexOf(searchStr, lastMatch + searchStr.length);
```

I add `searchStr.length` to prevent overlapping matches, e.g. searching for `abab` in `abababacccc`, there will be only 1 match found if I add `searchStr.length`. Change it to `+ 1` if you want to find all matches, regardless of overlapping.

Full example:

```
var lastMatch;
var result = [];

if ((lastMatch = str.indexOf(searchStr)) >= 0) {
    result.push(lastMatch);

    while ((lastMatch = str.indexOf(searchStr, lastMatch + searchStr.length)) >= 0) {
        result.push(lastMatch);
    }
}
```

### RegExp.exec

**This is to demonstrate the usage. For fixed string, use `String.indexOf` instead - you don't need the extra overhead with `RegExp` in fixed string case.**

As an example for [`RegExp.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

```
// Need g flag to search for all occurrences
var re = /jack/g;
var arr;
var result = [];

while ((arr = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    result.push(arr.index);
}
```

Note that the example above will give you non-overlapping matches. You need to set `re.lastIndex` if you want to find overlapping matches (no such thing for `"jack"` as search string, though).

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out this solution -to call the function that searches and replaces the original string recursively, until no more occurrences of the word are found:

```
function ReplaceUnicodeChars(myString) {    
    var pos = myString.search("&#");

    if (pos != -1) {
        // alert("Found unicode char in string " + myString + ", position " + pos);
        unicodeChars = myString.substr(pos, 6);
        decimalChars = unicodeChars.substr(2, 3);
        myString = myString.replace(unicodeChars, String.fromCharCode(decimalChars));
     }

    if (myString.search("&#") != -1)
        // Keep calling the function until there are no more unicode chars
        myString = ReplaceUnicodeChars(myString);

    return myString;       
}
```